# R language-statistics-significance testing

Tags: r, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R language and statistics hypergeometric test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/r-language-and-statistics-hypergeometric-test)

This is in reference to [my first question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/r-language-and-statistics-hypergeometric-test), although I have got an answer for it from Spacedman. But I am not entirely satisfied with the answer as it does not give me any sort of value (p or z value). So I am re-framing my question and posting it again. No offences to Mr.Spacedman.

I have a dictionary of say 61000 elements and out of this dictionary, I have two sets. Set A contains 23000 elements and Set B contains 15000 elements and an overlap of Set A and Set B gives 10000 elements. How can I estimate a p-value or z value to show that this overlap is significant and is not occuring by chance or vice versa.

Thank you in advance.